# Electrical commutator for a coffee machine

Tags: electrical

i would like to understand the role of the commutator in the following diagram.[image]

NB: abbreviations:

- Co: commutator
- Re:heating element
- Pr: pressure switch
- Sa: heating element protection
- Ct: power supply connector
- Ma Bv and Gv are colors

I have not a solid background on electrical engineering, the circuit is from CMA espresso coffee machine technical book.

Comment: Co isn't a "commutator", but a switch. This has to be a mistranslation from Italian. See the symbol =|) at the box.

Comment: It is actualy a commutator, as written in the technical book, i didn't translate anything, but took it as it is from the book.

Comment: As Janka said it's a switch , probably for small cup or large cup... maybe...

Comment: "The technical book" written by who? engineers or linguists : from experience engineering terms are a minefield for non-engineers...

Comment: If it is a switch, then can you explain the connections and the functioning?

Comment: A commutator is a switch, a multi-way switch. The word is most often met with DC motors.

Comment: Not gonna tilt my head sideways.  If you don't take your problem seriously, then there is no reason anyone here should either.

Comment: @OlinLathrop just put your laptop or monitor on it's side :)  peace! and I agree with you.

Comment: seriously, i looked for the rotary switch functioning, but found different symbols, and not that one. I got confused about the connections, and the role it plays. Can you focus on the question please.

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to be able to answer intelligently.  Do you have a data sheet or even a part number for the device in question?  At first, I thought that it might be a **contactor** but the wiring doesn't look like that.

Comment: The witing is why i am asking, i didn't get it. I don't have a datasheet for the part in question, the function has been kindly given, which is to switch t power from the heating element at the right of the picture to the the power connector at the bottom. What i want to know is the wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch appears to transfer the heater between the power source shown as R-N at the top/right side of the diagram and the CT power supply connector at the bottom/left. I have no idea why.

What is shown is a connection diagram rather than a schematic diagram. Rather than showing the switch function, the diagram shows a switch housing with wires connected to some of the terminals. The number of used and un-used terminals indicates that the switch has more contacts and functions than are required for this application.

The description quoted from the data sheet seems to require a double-pole, double-throw switch as shown schematically below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind answer, i know i that i have given few details but my knowledge is limited and i have not a solid understanding of electrical parts. I have read the technical book and found that the power connector powers the pump to fill the boiler woth water and the switching allows a full electrical power supply, including the heating element. The wiring and the symbol are the tricky part that troubles me. Thank you again sir.